# Normalisation clarification

Tags: normalization, database-normalization

Good day all

I am having a little problem here (bear in mind i am new to this) . I am building a very very small inventory system in principle. I have attempted to normalise my table. I am having a little problem that i will show, its when i get to the 3NF. 
This is the process

**UNF**

```
    Product (productID, productName, productBrand, productQuantityinstock, 
            productQuantitySold, productCost, adminstaffID, adminstaffName,
             adminstaffUserName  adminstaffPassword, productcategoryID, 
            productcategoryName, { customerID, customerName,      
           customerAddress, customerContact, serviceID,
           serviceType,serviceCost, serviceStatus, 
           serviceDetails, techstaffID, tsUsername, 
           techstaffPassword } )
```

**INF**

```
    Product (productID, productName, productBrand, productQuantityinstock, 
            productQuantitySold, productCost, adminstaffID, adminstaffName,
            adminstaffUserName  adminstaffPassword, productcategoryID, 
            productcategoryName)


    Product_Customer (productID, customerID, customerName, customerAddress, 
                      customerContact, serviceID, serviceType,       
                       serviceCost,serviceStatus, 
                       serviceDetails, techstaffID, tsUsername, 
                      techstaffPassword)
```

**2NF**

```
    Product (productID, productName, productBrand, productQuantityinstock, 
             productQuantitySold, productCost, adminstaffID, adminstaffName,
             adminstaffUserName  adminstaffPassword, productcategoryID, 
             productcategoryName)

    Product_Customer (productID*, customerID*)

    Customer (customerID, customerName, customerAddress, customerContact, 
              serviceID, serviceType, serviceCost, serviceStatus,    
              serviceDetails, techstaffID, tsUsername, 
              techstaffPassword)
```

**3NF**

```
     Product (productID, productName, productBrand, productQuantityinstock, 
              productQuantitySold, productCost, productcategoryID*,  
              adminstaffID* ,)

     Admin Staff (adminstaffID, adminstaffName, adminstaffUserName   
                  adminstaffPassword,)

     Product Category (productcategoryID, productcategoryName,)

     Product_Customer (productID*, customerID*)

     Customer ( customerID, customerName, customerAddress, customerContact) 

     Tech Staff ( techstaffID, techstaffUsername, techstaffPassword)

     Service (serviceID, serviceType, serviceCost, serviceStatus,  
              serviceDetails, customerID*, techstaffID*)
```

Above is what I did but i was advised that the in the 3NF form the customerID and techstaffID in the SERVICE table must go into the CUSTOMER table.

The system is designed so a customer may have one or many services and a tech staff will carry out one or many services. So i know that the foreign key always goes on the many side of a relationship so if

Customer to service will be 1-M with the many multiplicity on the service side

and

Techstaff to service will be 1 - M with the many multiplicity on the service side as well

I have attached an image of my ERD. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated as to where these two foreign keys should go.

[link to ERD, cant post images as yet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sxarx56jm4xz170/20150704_165814.jpg?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was advised that the in the 3NF form the customerID and techstaffID
>   in the SERVICE table must go into the CUSTOMER table.

Don't follow this advice. Your 3NF is fine. A Service call will involve a Customer and a TechStaff, so having their IDs as foreign keys in the `Service` table is correct. If you follow the advice, it will mean a customer is connected to a single tech staff for all his/her service requests.

Another suggestion that I have: why not combine the `TechStaff` and `AdminStaff` into one `Staff` table, like this:

```
Staff
(
    StaffID,
    StaffFullName,
    StaffUsername,
    StaffPassword,
    StaffTypeID -- use this column to determine if a staff is tech or admin
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will take you advice and merge the tables